# How do I use Chrome to open new tabs in google.com that are not location specific

Tags: google-chrome

I am using Google as my search engine. It always wants to redirect to a location-specific search page. So you always have to set this. Chrome always opens new tabs in location specific Google. I want this always to be Google.com. How can can set the default page for each new tab?

To avoid confusion, I am not asking for start up page, but a page for each new tab.

Comment: My only qualm about this being a duplicate is that the duplicate question does not address how to set the default page for each new tab.  That portion of the question might be better addressed to [SU], though.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you allowed Google.com to track your location at some point. This is a permission in the browser. If you'd like to disable location services in Google Chrome, you can follow these steps:

- Use the menu button in the upper right of the browser and go to "Settings", then use the "Show Advanced Settings" link at the bottom of the page
- Under "Privacy", you will click Content button
- About halfway through the resulting dialog, you'll find the "Location" section
- Select a permission level that fits your preference

From your question, it sounds like you don't object to other sites tracking your location, just the specific one. In this case you may want to use the default "Ask when a site tries to track your physical location" [image](https://screencast.com/t/ipZmT3B5ZNc), and use an exception to deny that to the specific site. You could also use the other two options to achieve the same thing. Here's [another article on this](https://shiftplanning.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205128900-How-to-Enable-Disable-Location-tracking-on-Google-Chrome-).